# Deploy and Run Angular 17 Universal SSR to Azure Service

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am trying to set up an Angular Universal SSR build and deploy it to Azure App Service.
I have already configured the project and the pipeline, as a result I got two folders that are deployed to Azure App Service.

I can open the browser folder through the domain that Azure gave me, but the server-side rendering doesn't work there.

The question is how to run the `main.js` file and point the Azure domain to the port `localhost:4000`

I don't know where I can run the `main.js` file and how to point the azure domain to the port `localhost:4000`

Comment: I think you just need to add a `web.config` with a `<handler ...>` tag which runs `npm start`

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/8ad0d30ac1b1aa3d0334)?

Comment: I haven't tried this configuration in web.config
Could you please share the web.config and .yml pipeline files?

Comment: Does it work fine when you deploy from local machine? This can help to narrow down the issue before you migrate to devops pipeline.

Comment: Yes, that works fine when I build and run the server locally

Comment: @Piterjan thanks for your comment. I updated the web.config and it helps me to run the server.js file

There is another problem. I can't set up the pipeline to get the next structure
- wwwroot
----- /browser folder
-----all the files from the /server folder
----- web.config

Answer (score 0):

I found out that these two tasks from the pipeline don't change the file structure after deployments

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy browser directory from dist directory to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/browser'
    Contents:  '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/browser'
        
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy main.js to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/server'
    Contents:  '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist'

- upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  artifact: drop

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

[file structure in /site/wwwroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3OWF.png)