Locally working correctly but when deploying on azure app service every thing working expect SSR. Not able to find what am I missing?
STEP 1 - I build .Net Core 8.0 Application(API Application)
STEP 2 - I Build Angular 17 SSR Application
STEP 3 - After ng build build command, I copied dist/server and dist/browser folder's file and pasted to .Net core wwwroot folder
STEP 4 - I have Deployed on Azure App service using publishedSetting option from visualstudio
Now every thing is working except SSR
On app.component.ts I have setup some title and it is working but not working on others pages
Can any body guide me?
here is sample code of demourl component
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title, TransferState } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from '../../../../../../environments/environment';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-url',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './demo-url.component.html',
  styleUrl: './demo-url.component.css',
})
export class DemoUrlComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = '';

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    private transferState: TransferState,
    private titleService: Title,
    private metaService: Meta
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      console.log('Server call 123');
      this.titleService.setTitle(`Server - My Demo Title`);
      this.metaService.addTag({
        name: 'Description',
        content: 'This is a test job description',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        name: 'keywords',
        content: 'Angular, Universal, TransferState, MetaService',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:title',
        content: 'My Demo Title',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:description',
        content: 'This is a test job description',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:image',
        content:
          'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:image:height',
        content: '1200',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:image:width',
        content: '1200',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:type',
        content: 'website',
      });
    } else if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.titleService.setTitle(`Browser - My Demo Title`);
      this.metaService.addTag({
        name: 'Description',
        content: 'This is a test job description',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        name: 'keywords',
        content: 'Angular, Universal, TransferState, MetaService',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:title',
        content: 'My Demo Title',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:description',
        content: 'This is a test job description',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:image',
        content:
          'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:image:height',
        content: '1200',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:image:width',
        content: '1200',
      });
      this.metaService.addTag({
        property: 'og:type',
        content: 'website',
      });
    }
  }
}

title set up for other pages should also be displayed on page view source file for SEO purpose

For this kind of issue, it's better to provide the repo which can reproduce the issue, then we can help you to check it.

I want steps, How to deploy angular 17 SSR Application; as i am getting deployment steps for angular universal only which is not working for me. My code is not on any repo for now or what file do you want?

Hi Dimpal, I am not familar with SSR,  could you provide the detailed steps, so that I can test in my side, many thanks.

use same steps what I have mentioned in post

@Dimpal - See the comments on this question, if you haven't seen them already. Especially the bits about the web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996709/deploy-and-run-angular-17-universal-ssr-to-azure-service

Hi @Dimpal, ok, please follow my steps to check the error message. 1. Deploy the project -> 2. Navigate to the folder and found the project_name.exe ->3. Double-click it. If it not works, show me the error message. This issue is not related to azure-web-app.

@Json Pan, I am new to SSR in angular,
I followed below steps -

I created one angular app with SSR
Run ng build command
After build we got two folder server and browser
After build I got server.mjs file and server.main.mjs file in server folder
Do I still require to create main.js and server.js files?
Can you please share me main.js and server.js and web.config if required


Thanks for your patience, Dimpal. After investigation, I found that there are no official out-of-the-box integrated AngulaR SSR-related packages or documents.

But I find a amazing package, you can search it via the keywords This project facilitates server-side prerendering in ASP.NET Core.

Finally I have separated my .net Core application with angular, now I have deployed my application to two azure app service where one is having .Net core runtime stack and another with nodejs where all angular build exists. and application is working fine now
